# Count number of leaves in a tree - Failed edge case?

Tags: python, tree

In an online assessment I was asked to count the number of leaves in a tree. The tree is given in parent-array representation, meaning the tree has n nodes with labels 0, 1, 2, .., n-1, and you are passed a length n array p, where p[i] returns the label of the parent of node i, except when i is the root of the tree in which case p[i] is -1.

I guess one thing to note is that the problem was as stated above, so there were no extra conditions such as e.g. it being a binary tree.

I thought this was a fairly straight forward problem, but the code that I submitted failed a "Small Tree Case" on the testing platform (which does not let you see the test cases). It passed the other tests, including a performance test on a large tree. I've thought about it for a while but I still can not see what the flaw in my algorithm or handling of some edge case is. I guess one thing to note is that the problem was as stated above, so there were no extra conditions such as e.g. it being a binary tree.

```py
def countLeaves(p):
    n = len(p)
    if p is None or n == 0 : return 0
    if n == 1 or n == 2 : return 1

    leaves = set(range(n))
    for i in range(n):
        if p[i] == -1: # i is root of tree with >1 node, can't be a leaf
            leaves.discard(i)
        else: # p[i] is parent of node i, can't be a leaf
            leaves.discard(p[i])

    return len(leaves)
```

In trying to fix the failed "Small tree case" I also tried returning None if p is None, returning None if n == 0, or both modifications together, but to no success. If anyone could point out what the error in my code may have been I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: what is the error u get

Comment: Can a node have multiple children?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What if it thinks a tree with one element (the root) has 0 leaves?

Comment: your code works fine for me, what is the "small tree case" that u tried it with?

Comment: @NullUserException i think in that case it return 1 without proceeding to the loop

Comment: @Eshaka That's what I'm saying, the code returns 1 but the assessment expects 0 as the answer

Comment: @lincr A node can have any amount of children, there were no extra conditions given than what I mentioned. I think NullUserException found the bug, that a tree with only one element, the root, is considered to have 0 leaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this:

```
def countLeaves(p):
    n = len(p)
    if p is None or n < 2 : return 0

    leaves = set(range(n))
    for i in range(n):
        if p[i] == -1: # i is root of tree with >1 node, can't be a leaf
            leaves.discard(i)
        else: # p[i] is parent of node i, can't be a leaf
            leaves.discard(p[i])

    return len(leaves)
```

The only real change is that it considers trees with a single node to have no leaves.

According to [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TreeLeaf.html):

> A leaf of an unrooted tree is a node of vertex degree 1. Note that for a rooted or planted tree, **the root vertex is generally not considered a leaf node**, whereas all other nodes of degree 1 are.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm guessing this must be the edge case I got wrong.